# Can I do Date calculation in React?

Tags: reactjs, date

Say, I just retrieved an object called "food" from the database. "food" has an attribute called "created_at" and it is created automatically when food was created. "food" also has an attribute called "shelf_life" Now, in a react frontend, I want to do a conditional rendering based on whether the food is expired or not. So, I need to do some calculations.

For example,

created_at = 2022-04-20T03:25:53.763+00:00
shelf_life = 30 (days)

Is there a way to do a calculation like created_at + shelf_life and compare the result to the current time?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the library `moment`
https://momentjs.com/

and declare your two dates

```
let date1 = moment('2022-04-20T03:25:53.763+00:00');
let date2 = moment('2022-04-11T03:25:53.763+00:00');
```

then get the difference in days using

```
var difference = date2.diff(date1, 'days');
```